# Netbeans C++ project not recognising source path added through Project Properties

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have a C++ project in Netbeans. I have added a source folder path (all configurations) by right-clicking the project -> Properties -> General

and lets say the path is:

/a/b/c

and in folder c I have a header file called File.h

in my C++ I put:

```
#include <File.h>
```

but it gives compile error:

```
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:16:21: fatal error: File.h: No such file or directory
 #include <File.h>
                 ^
```

compilation terminated.

However, if I do:

```
#include <a/b/c/File.h>
```

it does compile.

Anybody know what's happening here?

Comment: You need to add the directory of the header file to the *preprocessor* settings. That should cause the IDE to add a special `-I` (upper-case `i`) to the command when building. Something which is missing in the build-log you show.

Comment: For some reason NetBeans IDE isn't adding the I flag to the compile line, even though it knows it has added it in the project properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the Include Directories under Build/ C Compiler and Build / C++ Compiler in the project properties. These will generate the include flags for the compiler. Source folders are ( I think) where Netbeans looks for cpp files, but it will not pass them as include folders to the compiler.

[image: Set include folders]

If these files need also static libraries, you have to add the lib folders under the Linker tab.